# Aurelia: Add/Remove router.navigation Routes dynamically?

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to reconfigure a router.navigation to add/remove specific routes, and say have router.navigation automatically update the view?

My use case will be to have a route for multiple pages i.e. `/page/A`, `/page/B` and then to allow adding more while the app is running `/page/C`. I also want the navigation to show those specific pages in the menu: "Page A", "Page B" "Page C"

I believe there are parametrised routes available (`route:  'page/:id'`). But its not clear if you can give some context to the `router.navigation` to add some specific routes, via the parametrised route config.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this to add route:**

```
this.router.addRoute({ route: "pageA", moduleId: "views/pageA", nav: true, title: "PageA" });
this.router.refreshNavigation();
```

**To remove:**
Inspect the Navigation model an [remove the route](https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/129) that you want.

Comment: The routes are getting added but when I am trying to navigate to new route it is not happening.